# Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'createdAt' in 'field list'

Tags: node.js, sequelize-cli

I am working on `ORM` data base and I don't have `createdAt` column in table and I am using Sequelize `ORM` for db interaction.

I am getting the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'createdAt' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 3):

The above error comes when db adapter want to store tiemstamp columns. We can exclude the createdAt/updatedAt column while doing db operation by disabling timestamp.

example.

```
"define": {
      "timestamps": false
    }
```

We can add above line in side the code before calling the models. So I have put the above code inside config.json. Below is the complete code.

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "xxxx",
    "password": "xxxx",
    "database": "dbName",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "define": {
      "timestamps": false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your associations of all the models, I also faced the same issue and found that I wrote wrong model name in the associations declaration.

```js
models.Page.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'createdBy' });
```